# Non-exhaustive pattern matching in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I am learning Haskell and wanted to write a simple program which just repeats each letter in a string twice.

I came up with this:

```
repl :: String -> String
repl " " = " "
repl (x:xs) = x:x:repl xs
```

When compiling, I didnt get any warning but a run-time error occurred when I did `repl "abcd"`:

> "abcd*** Exception: repl.hs:(2,1)-(3,23): Non-exhaustive patterns in function repl

Why did the compiler never report this and why is it ignored in Haskell when there are many languages like OCaml which clearly report this at compile time?

Comment: `ghc -fwarn-incomplete-patterns` seems appropriate...

Comment: It should give a warning if compiled with -Wall. Specifically, the flag -fwarn-incomplete-patterns checks for this

Answer (score 22, accepted):

The pattern match warning is turned off by default. You can turn it on with the `-fwarn-incomplete-patterns` or as part of a larger bundle of warnings with `-W` and `-Wall`.

You can do this from `ghci`:

```
Prelude> :set -W
```

You can also pass the flag to `ghc` when you compile or include it as a pragma on top of your module:

```
{-# OPTIONS_GHC -fwarn-incomplete-patterns #-}
```

For your specific program, it should give the following warning:

```
/home/tjelvis/Documents/so/incomplete-patterns.hs:2:1: Warning:
    Pattern match(es) are non-exhaustive
    In an equation for ‘repl’: Patterns not matched: []
```

Comment: OK and can you tell which patterns I missed in above code?

Comment: " " is a string containing one space. [] is the empty list, which is also the empty string. You could also have written "", without the space.

Comment: @AbhinavJain: You missed the empty string. (`" "` is the string with a single space character.)

Comment: @AbhinavJain: The compiler will tell you if you turn this warning on and compile your code.

Comment: @TikhonJelvis yes i just saw it.