# Is it possible for GHC to find all the places that uses partial functions?

Tags: haskell, ghc

Is it possible for GHC to give warning when I define a partial function like this:

```
f :: Maybe Int -> Int
f (Just i) = i
```

and when I use a partial function like this:

```
f :: [Int] -> Int
f = head
```

Comment: [`-Wincomplete-patterns`](https://downloads.haskell.org/~ghc/latest/docs/html/users_guide/using-warnings.html#ghc-flag--Wincomplete-patterns)? Might be easier to just `-Wall`.

Comment: [`hlint`](http://community.haskell.org/~ndm/darcs/hlint/hlint.htm) will catch usages.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Haskell - Non-exhaustive pattern matching in haskell](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31866379/haskell-non-exhaustive-pattern-matching-in-haskell)